# JavaScript: Listening for browser tab change

Tags: javascript, events, browser, tabs

I'm trying to trigger an event on browser tab change in JavaScript. MDN advertises a [`browser.tabs.onActivated()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onActivated) function, and shows full support in Chrome, but my Chrome console barks when I try to access either `browser` or `tabs` global variables.

Does anyone know how to trigger an event on change of browser tab? I'm looking for a vanilla solution without external library dependencies.

Comment: browser.tabs.onActivated is a part of API for create browser add-ons. The API methods can't be called from a client-side code on simple web page.

Comment: Interesting, what are browser add ons?

Comment: Add-ons or extensions - take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  console.log('the tab hath changed');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'visibilitychange' event and 'hidden' attribute.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => console.log(document.hidden));
```